# PHP zipping files without saving to local directory

Tags: php, laravel, php-ziparchive

I want to zip some images using Laravel, but I can't figure out how to zip those images without storing to local directory first. Is it possible doing so without saving them to my local directory? I have PHP 7.1 running on my local machine.

From official docs of [ZipArchive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php), the file could only be add to the zip if it's already stored in local directory.

Here is some snippets of my code for zipping a single image:

```
Use Image;
Use ZipArchive();
$image = Image::make('http://example-image.com');
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->addFile($image, 'image-filename');
```

Expected behaviour: The image will be inserted to the `$zip`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to upload an  image, zip it and store somewhere?

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov I want to store it at my AWS S3 as a zipped file.

Comment: You have two options: 1. Zip your file before uploading it, or 2. Upload your file then zip it.

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov yeah bro, your first option is what my question about. Is it possible to zip the files after being uploaded to S3?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [addFromString](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php):

```
$zip->addFromString('image-filename.png', $image->encode('png'));
```

or

```
$zip->addFromString('image-filename.png', $image->encode('jpg', $quality));
```

Comment: This don't work. Have you tried it? I got `Error 500: Command (Get) is not available for driver (Gd)`

Comment: No I didn't try it, I don't use Laravel and I assumed that you are using another library. I've updated the answer so that should work with [Intervention library](https://github.com/Intervention/image).

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
$zip->addFile($_FILE['tmp_name'], $_FILE['name']);
```

add to zip from the temp location

Comment: I'm not processing uploaded image from HTTP POST data. It's a valid image URL.